# Import Swift Package in Xcode11

Tags: swift, xcode11, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to import an SPM package in Xcode11. I can fetch the library and see it in the project as **Swift Package Dependencies** but when trying to import, Xcode doesn't find it. 
I read that the problem could be custom configurations and not the standard e.g. **Debug**.

Does anyone know how to solve this without renaming the configuration names?

Answer (score 2):

The best advice at the moment is [this](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-package-manager-and-custom-build-configurations/29181/5) post on the Swift forums where Ankit says:

> This is a known issue that Apple folks are tracking internally. Currently, Swift packages default to the "Release" configuration when anything other than Debug and Release is used. In theory, adding `$(BUILD_DIR)/Release` to `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS` build setting for the custom configurations should work around this issue but it can lead to some weird errors in case something unexpected gets picked from that directory.

Comment: Thx a lot for that info!

Comment: we need to set SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS = $(BUILD_DIR)/Release in the Package.swift file? How do we set Debug, Release, Adhoc these kind of settings

Comment: Only debug and release builds are supported at the moment. It is a known issue and feature request but Apple hasn’t given any updates on it beyond that.